# SQLite: Select row based on time of day?

Tags: sqlite, datetime, time

I have a SQLite table like the following:

```
+-----------+-------+
| StartTime | Name  |
+-----------+-------+
|  08:00:00 | zone1 |
|  13:00:00 | zone2 |
|  17:30:00 | zone3 |
|  22:00:00 | zone4 |
+-----------+-------+
```

I'm trying to write a query that will return the row  based on the current time:

If CurrentTime is 08:30 it will return zone1
If CurrentTime is 16:40 it will return zone2
If Currenttime is 04:01 it will return zone4

and so on...

So far I had some luck but not exactly what I wanted

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE StartTime >= time('now', 'localtime') 
ORDER BY StartTime LIMIT 1;
```

I've tried some variations of the above statement, but none returns the result I'm after.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll make your life a lot easier if you add an "EndTime" field as well, as you can then simply check if the current time is within the start and end time.

For example, if your database table consisted of the following...

```
+-----------+----------+-------+
| StartTime | EndTime  | Name  |
+-----------+----------+-------+
|  08:00:00 | 12:59:59 | zone1 |
|  13:00:00 | 17:29:59 | zone2 |
|  17:30:00 | 21:59:59 | zone3 |
|  22:00:00 | 07:59:59 | zone4 |
+-----------+----------+-------+
```

...you could simply use a query along the lines of:

```
SELECT Name FROM table WHERE StartTime >= time('now', 'localtime')
AND EndTime <= time('now', 'localtime')
ORDER BY StartTime LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to avoid adding an extra field. It's easier to for the user to add/remove a row to the table if he only defines the time that the zone starts without the danger of zones overlapping.

Comment: @LaLeX: You can construct a view that holds the extra column necessary to make querying easier. You'll also want to take extra care with the over-midnight section, as that might need splitting if there is no real zone starting at that time (picking any other split time would have the same problem, of course; the issue is that there is a seam). It might also be easier to have the end time be the moment after the end and use `<` as the relation, so you do less time arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a having clause?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE StartTime >= time('now', 'localtime')
HAVING StartTime = MIN(StartTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two versions.

This is the easiest to understand, but it assumes that `max(Name)` is meaningful. That is, it assumes that the values in "Name" are ordered from low to high.

```
SELECT max(Name) 
FROM yourtable
WHERE StartTime< time("16:40:00");
```

This version uses a scalar subquery. It doesn't depend on any meaningful order to the names. I'd consider this version to be more robust.

```
SELECT Name 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE StartTime = (SELECT max(StartTime) 
                   FROM yourtable
                   WHERE StartTime < time("16:40:00")
);
```

- You'll want to replace the time()
  literals with
  `time('now','localtime')` in
  production.
- Expect an empty set if you run any of
  these queries before 08:00 local
  time.

Comment: Well it will not return any rows if time is after 22:00:00 or before 08:00:00, for the given table values... It should return 22:00:00...

Comment: No, SQLite3 will return 'Zone4' between 22:00 and 24:00. In fact, it will return 'Zone4' until a literal time value of "24:59:59", which I didn't even know was a valid value until just now.