# How do I select from two tables, nearest timestamp and order by said timestamp?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, timestamp

My current query:

```
SELECT Series.*, Episodes.* FROM Series, Episodes
WHERE EpisodeAirDate > '.time().' AND Episodes.SeriesKey = Series.SerieID
GROUP BY Series.SerieTitle ORDER BY Episodes.EpisodeAirDate;
```

I want to retrieve the information from Episodes where Episodes.EpisodeAirDate is the closest to the current time (time()). With this I just get the last episode in the database.

I've tried with

```
SELECT Series.*, Episodes.*, MIN(Episodes.EpisodeAirDate) AS EpisodeAirDate FROM Series, Episodes
WHERE EpisodeAirDate > '.time().' AND Episodes.SeriesKey = Series.SerieID
GROUP BY Series.SerieTitle ORDER BY EpisodeAirDate;
```

which kind of works, but Episode.EpisodeTitle etc. does not correspond with the timestamp row.

Here I'm using the MIN()-query (http://grab.by/8UNY). I wasn't allowed to post an image, so perhaps a link will suffice :)

As you can see, the SerieTitle and "Time until" is correct, but the EpisodeTitle, EpNo and SeasonNo is that of the first query.

It's hard to explain, really. I hope you make sense of this! :)

Comment: is there a problem using the MySQL `NOW()` or `TIME()` function? Have you checked out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906589/sqlite-select-row-based-on-time-of-day/4906655#4906655)?

Comment: If you have a very small database, the easy answer is to break this into a multi-step process: select all episodes, then loop through them, and query for the upcoming episode for each series separately. Not elegant or fast....

Comment: jswolf19: Thanks, no. I'll definitely check that out when I get home. Mark Eirich: Yeah, I could, but that is my last resort because of how ugly it'll be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SELECT S.*,E.* FROM Series S
JOIN (SELECT SeriesKey, MIN(EpisodeAirDate) MinDate FROM Episodes
    WHERE EpisodeAirDate > NOW() GROUP BY SeriesKey) M
    ON M.SeriesKey = S.SerieID
JOIN Episodes E ON E.SeriesKey = S.SerieID AND E.EpisodeAirDate = M.MinDate
ORDER BY E.EpisodeAirDate;
```

**Edit:** Added the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: regarding your suggested edit: The typical suggestion is to be very cautious in editing people's *code*. Beyond adjusting whitespace (indentation) and ensuring the markdown recognizes it as code, you should refrain from making any modifications. The reason is you never know if what you're fixing could be the very thing (or *one* of the things) that is keeping their code from working properly in the first place. The query syntax in the question is indeed wrong, but if the asker doesn't know the *correct* way to write it, that might be why it isn't working. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I'm quite certain I only edited whitespace, and did not edit the syntax in any way. The query, as originally entered, has `Series.*, Episodes.*` in it, but because of the incorrect formatting/whitespace, it displays without the asterisks (they are interpreted as italics markup).

Comment: Ah, fair enough. The side-by-side comparison we're given for reviewing purposes isn't always perfectly accurate... In particular, I couldn't see the original raw text that was entered. You're right about the edit being perfectly valid. My apologies. Feel free to edit the question again, if you want.

Comment: That certainly did the trick. Thanks a lot :) I did however need to add one little bit (ORDER BY) for it to fully work. For full disclosure, here's the final query: SELECT S.*, E.* FROM Series S
JOIN (SELECT SeriesKey, MIN(EpisodeAirDate) MinDate FROM Episodes
    WHERE EpisodeAirDate > '.time().' GROUP BY SeriesKey) M
    ON M.SeriesKey = S.SerieID
JOIN Episodes E ON E.SeriesKey = S.SerieID AND E.EpisodeAirDate = M.MinDate ORDER BY E.EpisodeAirDate

Comment: @John Doe: I'm glad it worked for you. I'd still like to see an even simpler solution to this. I checked Google and found several people asking the same question, but no one seemed to even have a solution. Anyway, I think this one probably has respectable performance.